# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000001c (code=1), thread 18178

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation, skmaps

I am trying to use navigation in Skobbler maps. It was working well when route is created using 'creatRoute' but then i get this error list as shown below when i use 'createRouteWithPoints':

```
05-16 09:33:16.948 27932-27932/com.wolfmatrix.navz E/SKRouteManager: GPX track navigation is available for commercial use with a enterprise license
05-16 09:33:16.948 27932-27932/com.wolfmatrix.navz A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000001c (code=1), thread 27932 (wolfmatrix.navz)
05-16 09:33:18.088 30617-30617/com.wolfmatrix.navz E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method com.wolfmatrix.navz.ui.activities.DrawClusterActivity.access$super
05-16 09:33:18.088 30617-30617/com.wolfmatrix.navz E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.Toolbar', referenced from method com.wolfmatrix.navz.ui.activities.DrawClusterActivity.access$super
05-16 09:33:18.098 30617-30617/com.wolfmatrix.navz E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method com.wolfmatrix.navz.ui.activities.DrawClusterActivity.access$super
05-16 09:33:18.098 30617-30617/com.wolfmatrix.navz E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.wolfmatrix.navz.ui.activities.DrawClusterActivity.access$super
05-16 09:33:18.108 30617-30617/com.wolfmatrix.navz E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.wolfmatrix.navz.ui.activities.DrawClusterActivity.access$super
05-16 09:33:18.118 30617-30617/com.wolfmatrix.navz E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.assist.AssistContent', referenced from method com.wolfmatrix.navz.ui.activities.DrawClusterActivity.access$super
05-16 09:33:18.118 30617-30617/com.wolfmatrix.navz E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.SearchEvent', referenced from method com.wolfmatrix.navz.ui.activities.DrawClusterActivity.access$super
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 2.5.1 was delivered a quick fix for this issue a few months ago:http://forum.skobbler.com/showthread.php/7257-Android-SIGSEGV-error-in-calculateRouteWithPoints%28%29

Comment: I have already followed the process as discussed in the forum, I am still getting those errors.

Comment: Please send us the track (GPS points) at dev@telenav.com and we'll investigate forward